# Django Heroku Commit Failure at Requirements

Tags: python, django, heroku

I am receiving the following error when I try and deploy my new app to Heroku. It looks like it's failing when it tries to install all of my requirements.txt line items, specifically at PyAudio which I am not using in my app at all.

My requirements file was generated using `pip freeze > requirements.txt` which has 155 line items (seems way high for my simple app). Is this what's causing the issue?

```
-----> Python app detected
-----> Installing python-3.6.12
-----> Installing pip 20.1.1, setuptools 47.1.1 and wheel 0.34.2
-----> Installing SQLite3
-----> Installing requirements with pip
       ERROR: PyAudio-0.2.11-cp38-cp38-win_amd64.whl is not a supported wheel on this platform.
 !     Push rejected, failed to compile Python app.
 !     Push failed
```

Comment: Have you used a [virtual environment](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/venv.html) for development? If you didn't you will find all dependencies of the system Python and all other projects in your `requirements.txt`.

Comment: i would not recomment using pip freeze command. why don't you just add the required libraries inside the requirements.txt file

Answer (score 0):

Try installing pyaudio separatly using [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-3am_5jMzJ4) link.